# Find sometimes generates Run time error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table with column headings. I have a list of column headings that I don't want.

I want to delete the unwanted column headings no matter where they are in the worksheet and the ability for users to add other columns to delete.

I get

> run time 91 error

on this line: `ws.Rows("1:1").Select.Find(T).EntireColumn.Delete`

Sometimes I will get an error in the first loop of the code, sometimes it will be part way through.

I have looked at other posts but the problems have not be related enough for me to problem solve my way through.  I tried reading some articles on defining objects.  I have been using the msgbox command to make sure the code is finding the values and that seems to be working all the time but it breaks down at the `Find` command.

```
Sub DeleteBadHeaders2()
    Dim FirstHeading As Range
    Set FirstHeading = Worksheets("Headings_To_Delete").Range("a2")
'Worksheet that has all the column headings I want deleted
    Dim x As Integer
'x is for the do while loop to individually highlight each cell
    Dim y As Long
    y = Worksheets("Headings_To_Delete").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
'y acts as the upper bound to the headings to delete column for the while loop
    Dim T As Variant
'T acts as a temporary value holder that will be used to delete the proper columns
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    x = 0
    Do While x < (y - 1)
        Worksheets("Headings_To_Delete").Range("a2").Offset(x, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(224, 0, 0)
'Calling the rage as above fixes the active cell problem
        Let T = Worksheets("Headings_To_Delete").Range("a2").Offset(x, 0).Value
        'MsgBox T & " is found."
        ws.Rows("1:1").Select.Find(T).EntireColumn.Select
        'for testing switch the last part of the code to EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 225, 0)
        x = x + 1
     Loop
'The loop is highlighting the cells incrementally based on the first active cell until the upper limit of how many cells are in the column
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.Find` should never have chained member calls. `Set` the result of `Range.Find` to some `Range` object variable, and verify whether that reference `Is Nothing` before you make any member calls on it. `Range.Find` returns `Nothing` when it doesn't find what it's looking for - and any member calls made against `Nothing` will throw error 91.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ws.Rows("1:1").Select.Find(T).EntireColumn.Select
```

should be

```
ws.Rows(1).Find(T).EntireColumn.Select  'Delete?
```

Typically though whenever using `Find()` it's a good idea to check you actually found anything, by testing the return value for `Nothing` before trying to do anything like `Select` or `Delete`.

Also a good idea to be explicit about some of the other parameters in Find, such as `lookAt` for example.

Something like this:

```
Sub DeleteBadHeaders()

    Dim r As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim T As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsList As Worksheet, f As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set wsList = Worksheets("Headings_To_Delete")
    lastRow = wsList.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        T = wsList.Cells(r, "A").Value
        If Len(T) > 0 Then
            Set f = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:=T, lookat:=xlWhole)
            'check to see if the heading was found
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Found header '" & T & "' at " & f.Address
                f.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = vbRed  '<< for testing
                'f.EntireColumn.Delete                 '<< uncomment when done testing
            End If   'was found
        End If       'any heading
     Next r          'next in list

End Sub
```

Comment: Worth noting, this will throw a 91 error if `T` is not found in the range :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - that's the crux of my note just below the code.

Comment: When I msgbox T all the values I am looking for show up?  Should T be defined as a range?